# How can I create child views dynamically in MVVM Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, data-binding

I am new to MVVM in Android.
Is there a way to add child views of group layout such as chipgroup, radiogroup? 
Let's say there is this kind of data from a server.

```
[name: 'coffee', size: 'tall', 'grande', 'venti' ...,
 name: 'pizza', size: 'small', 'medium', 'large' ...]
```

And here is what I have done so far:
**main XML** 
`itemViewModels` is a custom BindingAdapter to bind between RecyclerViewAdapter and listItems

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
  app:itemViewModels="@{vm.listItem}"
  app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager"/>
```

**ViewModel**

```
val listItem = MutableLiveData<List<ItemViewModel>>(...)
listItem= ... // get data and convert into view data blabla
```

**ItemViewModel**

```
class ItemViewModel() {
  val name:String
  val size:List<String>
}
```

**item XML**

```
<TextView android:text="@{itemViewModel.data.name}" .../>
<com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup
  android:id="@+id/chipGroupSizeOption">
  <!-- I would like to add child views of chipgroup here -->
</com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup>
```

In MVC pattern, I would write this like

```
binding.chipGroupSizeOption.removeAllViews()
SizeOptionsDataFromServer.forEach { x->
  val chip= (LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.chip_item, 
  binding.chipGroupSizeOption, false) as Chip)
    .apply {
    text = x.data.name
    id = ViewCompat.generateViewId()
  }
}
binding.chipGroupSizeOption.addView(chip)
```

but in MVVM, is it possible to add child views with data-binding?
Should I use BindingAdapter to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

So, you have your `list_view_item` in your layout resources.
In this item layout, there is a chip group that will display the list from the object. Example User.nicknames

I'm guessing in this list_view_item layout, you have defined the object variable. Something like

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<data>
    <variable
        name="user"
        type="com.myapp.data.User" />
</data>
<ConstraintLayout... /> <!-- UI layout's root element -->
```

Now, create a binding adapter, you can do so by creating a new kotlin file, which will contain all the adapters it will take a chipGroup and the list of items to display. Here is one from my use case

```
@BindingAdapter("childChipValues")
fun bindChildChips(chipGroup: ChipGroup, childChipValues:List<String>) {
    childChipValues.forEach{ value ->
        val chip = Chip(chipGroup.context)
        chip.text = value
        chipGroup.addView(chip)
    }
}
```

Next, what you want to do is go back to the chipGroup layout and use the adapter. Something like

```
<com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup
                android:id="@+id/levels"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:childChipValues="@{user.nicknames}"
                app:singleSelection="false" />
```

You can read more about binding adapters [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/binding-adapters)